# Is it possible to simplify build configurations for a Xamarin Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild

I created a new Xamarin App from this template:
[image]

which has the following projects (Called NewApp):

- NewApp
- NewApp.Droid
- NewApp.iOS

The build configurations for iOS are:
[image]
 but for Android I have:
[image]

is there a way to simplify the Android configuration to be like the iOS one with only Debug and Release?

I tried to create more platforms like `AndroidEmulator` and `AndroidDevice` from this [link](https://blog.xamarin.com/demystifying-build-configurations/) but I think the IDE is doing something to hide the other options on iOS. Has anyone ever simplified the build configs?

Comment: I change the Android ones all the time (I strip the AnyCPU and add `Android` configurations, so only the .NetStd libraries have AnyCPU configurations, etc...  (mainly this is for DevOps-style build scripts)   BUT once I do that, then **all** the configurations show up under the Android OR the iOS project... VS4M handles the default build configurations, but once they are edited its auto-"magic" configurations list disappears.

Comment: Ah OK, so it is not possible to get it to automagically hide the other options. Its weird tho as Android - Debug | iPhone builds the app properly so must default to AnyCPU. Ah well, thanks for your help 

Comment: Just a note, the `AnyCPU` in the Configuration Platform is "just a name" as it has nothing to do with the actual "compiler platform target" option which is kind-of legacy now as it has nothing to due with the final JIT'd or AOT'd platform other then the metadata insertion (i.e. Mono respects the assembly metadata for x86 or x86_64 to toggle the runtime between Mono32 and Mono64, but the "Itanium" option? Hahahaha, how many people are building for Intel Itanium anymore, and I do not think the Rosyln compiler or RyuJIT have any custom pathways for it... Time for  and then 

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update configurations, but I suspect that is now what you want to do. The lists are likely varying for another reason.

All of the configurations are there for both. When your project is set to iOS, Visual Studio Mac will usually see what device you have selected and make the choice of iPhone or iPhoneSimulator for you and filter out options that don't make sense -- usually.

Other times you may have to select an simulator to get the iPhoneSimulator options to show. Having a device plugged in whose iOS version is compatible with your project will also affect if it shows up in the list of devices. It is one of the situations where Visual Studio Mac is trying to be helpful, but may end up being confusing.

You *can* update configurations, but you may want to do that for other reasons than just limiting visibility in the configuration list.